# check Organic Traffic vs PPC

Tags: javascript, traffic

is there a simple script that can check whether I got traffic from Google Organic or PPC? that would not involve using any google API's.

would something like this be enough?

```
if (document.referrer) {
            var ref = document.referrer;
            if (ref.toLowerCase.search("http://www.google.co.uk/aclk?") || ref.toLowerCase.search("www.googleadservices.com")) {
                alert("PPC");
            }
            if (ref.toLowerCase.search("http://www.google.co.uk/url?")) {
                alert("Organic");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("no referrer");
        }
```

Or maybe on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely on the server side and yes, that would work for the vast majority of your traffic.

Maybe you should optimize your string comparison a little bit more (maybe regular expressions) for cases where users may be using google with HTTPS or another domain than .co.uk.

Why don't you use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) though?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Tom, I believe Google Analytics only gives info about the traffic, but I need to trigger some code on the site depending on where the user came from.

Comment: In that case you can use backend or frontend, depending where the code to trigger is.